# mounted volumes don't get filled with docker image content

Tags: docker, coreos, rkt

I'm running `Container Linux by CoreOS 1618.0.0 (Ladybug)`.

with `rkt Version: 1.29.0`

I created a systemd service file to run a docker nagios image:

```
[Unit]
Description=Nagios
Requires=network-online.target local-fs.target
After=network-online.target local-fs.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Slice=machine.slice
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rkt run --port=80-tcp:8018 --insecure-options=image --volume volume-var-log-apache2,kind=host,source=/mnt/storage/nagios/apache2-log --volume volume-usr-share-snmp-mibs,kind=host,source=/mnt/storage/nagios/snmp-mibs --volume volume-opt-nagiosgraph-etc,kind=host,source=/mnt/storage/nagios/nagiosgraph/etc --volume volume-opt-nagiosgraph-var,kind=host,source=/mnt/storage/nagios/nagiosgraph/var --volume volume-opt-nagios-libexec,kind=host,source=/mnt/storage/nagios/nagios/libexec --volume volume-opt-nagios-var,kind=host,source=/mnt/storage/nagios/etc,readOnly=false --volume volume-opt-nagios-etc,kind=host,source=/mnt/storage/nagios/var,readOnly=false --volume volume-opt-custom-nagios-plugins,kind=host,source=/mnt/storage/nagios/custom-plugins docker://jasonrivers/nagios:latest
KillMode=mixed
Restart=always
RestartSec=0
ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/rkt gc --mark-only
```

now the problem is that the mounted parittions don't get populated with the relevant image files.

usually what I do is to extract the image itself and copy the relevant files manually.

the question is... is there another?

hopefully I missed a rkt parameter that fills the relevant mounted directories with the files in the docker image in the mounted locations

any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *not* expect to see the volume automatically populated with whatever files exist in the image at that particular mount point. In fact the opposite happens, the (presumably empty) volume *hides* what's in the image. See this: https://github.com/appc/spec/blob/master/spec/ace.md#volume-setup

So, if you want to pre-populate the volumes with files from the image, I believe you're doing the right thing by extracting the image manually.